# Failed to pin chainbase shared memory (of size 1024 MB) in RAM

Tags: nodeos, mainnet

When I started nodeos, I got:

`CHAINBASE:   Failed to pin chainbase shared memory (of size 1024 MB) in RAM. Performance degradation is possible.`

Memory is enough(more than 6GB available), so why is this? And what can I do?

Comment: Same happens after a reboot of your computer?

Comment: Yes, everytime. I am running node inside docker.

Comment: same issue...Did you guys able to resolve this issue?

Comment: see [#4632](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/4632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Using docker `cap_add` option to add `IPC_LOCK` privilege resolves this issue.

---

This is actually a docker-related question.

Process in docker container needs `IPC_LOCK` privilege to pin memory, which means prohibiting its memory page being swapped into swap.

More info: [#4632](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/4632)